# Secondary line text flowing into number column <ol> ordered list

Tags: html, css, list

I'm using an order list to display some information. I'm overriding my site's default centre align by aligning the list left, which is working. But I don't want the secondary lines of text to flow into the number area. [image]

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please post a jsfiddle, although the following css should help

```
ol {
    list-style-position: outside;
}
```

Here is a link to a Codepen showing this in action

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AgzDq

Comment: it's worth noting that `list-style-position` is `outside` by default, so looks like the OP has some code explicitly setting it to `inside` somewhere else.

Comment: @KingKing thanks for the comment a worthy note indeed, since there was no fiddle or example code it was hard to specifically know the cause of this problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest widening the area containing the text so it doesn't have to spill an extra line. Or just decrease the text size.